# Instruct win32 threads to run on a single processor core

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I have a test program which would be much simpler if it could rely on threads being scheduled in strict priority order on Windows.  I'm seeing a low priority thread running alongside higher priority threads and wonder if this is happening because the different threads are being scheduled on different processor cores.

Is there a way to force all Win32 threads in a process to use a single processor core?  [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) looks like it might be interesting but its docs aren't entirely clear and I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SetThreadAffinityMask function: Sets a processor affinity mask for the specified thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(), (1 << CoreNumber));
```

Sets the current thread's affinity to 'CoreNumber' variable

Comment: Note: For "private" testing I'd suggest not to use `Core 0` because most windows interrupt handling is bound to `Core 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you force all threads onto one virtual processor you will still often have low-priority threads running and high-priority threads waiting for them ([priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion)). Once a thread is scheduled by the windows-scheduler it runs until it is either preempted or sleeps (or some other sleep-inducing system call). You will have to change the design of your application so that it no-longer assumes that no low-priority thread runs while a high-priority thread would be ready to run also.

Comment: That's what "strict priority order" means... the low threads run if and only if high priority threads are all blocked.  Your last two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: Doesn't priority inversion only happen if the lower-priority thread manages to lock a resource that the higher-priority thread tries to grab? I still agree nothing's granted.

Comment: The core the OP wants to force all threads on is one such resource, if a low-prio thread gets a hold of that processor, then it will "block" the processor-"resource" even while some higher prio threads have been ready for a few milliseconds.

Comment: @eznme Thanks for the reply.  I'm familiar with the problems caused by priority inversion but had assumed windows scheduling would use priority inheritance to temporarily raise the priority of a low priority thread, reducing that thread's priority and rescheduling when the resource under contention was released.  My test would behave sensibly under this scheduling model.  Does windows scheduling not work like this?

Comment: Hmm.. can you run your tests on another box?  An old Pentium, or a atomic single-core netbook with HT disabled in BIOS?

Comment: @simonc The resource being contended here is the cpu-core itself. If a low priority thread is scheduled and then - as soon as it runs - a high priority thread becomes available also, then the low priority thread will still run its whole time-slice (ie until pre-empted) unless it syscalls. If your program assumes that a low priority thread will not run if a high priority thread is also ready then you have to change your program, because that can happen if the low-prio thread became ready before the high-prio thread became ready.

Comment: @eznme: [Context Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do happen when a thread with a higher priority becomes available. The time slice of a thread with a lower priority will not be completed. Instead a context switch will occur to start the higher prioritized thread immediately.

Comment: @Arno yes pre-emption. see my answers above. However, if OP's application depends on low-prio threads not running while high-prio threads available any millisecond can eg trash his application-logic.

Comment: @simonc: Windows does not have priority inheritance.

Comment: @NeerajSingh Thanks.  [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684831(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests that Windows does pay some attention to priority inversion but the imprecise language doesn't suggest proper priority inheritance.  Although, surprisingly, [Windows mobile does seem to have this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915356.aspx).